# Rearrangement of an infinite sum always gives zero

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let me consider an infinite sum (which we don't assume to have any specific property)
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i.
\end{equation}
Then, let me do the following operations on this sum. We start by rewriting
\begin{equation}
a_i=\sum_{j=0}^i a_{i-j}-\sum_{j=1}^{i}a_{i-j}=\sum_{j=0}^i a_{i-j}-\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{i-j-1}
\end{equation}
which can be done for $i>0$. Then we insert this in the initial sum, to obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^i a_{i-j}-\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a_{i-j-1}.
\end{equation}
Finally, we re-absorb the $a_0$ in the first sum
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^i a_{i-j}-\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a_{i-j-1},
\end{equation}
and we relabel the second sum
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^i a_{i-j}-\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{i} a_{i-j}=0,
\end{equation}
which gives zero, independently of the sum we started with. This type of manipulation reminds me of those flawed arguments using the "division-by-zero" to argue that 1=0, or stuff like that. I'm interested in which step of this derivation is wrong.

Comment: Can you do this with $\infty$ replaced by a finite $n$ ?

Comment: Where does this go wrong when $a_n=\frac1{2^n}$ and the original sum is clearly $2$?

Comment: Don't play with $\large \infty$

Comment: If you write out your sums with ellipses, so $a_0 + a_1 +  \cdots$ instead of an indexed expression using $\Sigma$ you should find your error.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I now understand where the issue lies! I gave the "best answer" based on the oldest answer, but thank you all nonetheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the equality$$a_0+\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^i a_{i-j}-\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a_{i-j-1}.\tag1$$It is actually correct that$$a_0+\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=0}^i a_{i-j}-\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a_{i-j-1}\right),$$but you cannot deduce $(1)$ from this.

Answer (score 2):

If for example $a_n$ is always positive and  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}$ is finite, you have the double sum $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=0}^i a_{i-j} \ge \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=i}^i a_{i-j}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_{0} =+\infty$$

so you are in effect adding and then subtracting infinity (similar to multiplying and dividing by $0$)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very clear!